# Como recargar un componente de angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routerlink

Tengo una pagina (A) que muestra el resultado de una petición get, y tengo un botón para regresar a una pagina (B)

```
back() {
        this.location.back();
    }
```

y de esta pagina B hay otro botón para ir a (A) usando el router link

```
[routerLink]="[ 'option' ]"
```

El problema es que cuando estoy en A le doy en back para ir a B y quiero regresar a A con el botón de `routerlink` ya no me carga el componente en A tengo que darle en recargar para que se muestre la pagina.

Mi método get lo tengo en el ngOnInit igual intente ponerlo en el constructor, pero sigue sin cargarse cuando regreso a la pagina

Este es mi petición get y en ella filtro los registros repetidos para que solo se muestren 1 vez

```
this.servService.getFiltar(this.url).subscribe(resp => {
            this.result = resp;
            this.result.Rowsets.Rowset.forEach(element => {

                element.Row.forEach(s => {
                    this.data.push(s);

                    this.oData = this.result.Rowsets.Rowset[0].Row;

                    for (let item of this.oData) {

                        if (!unicos.includes(item.nombre)) {
                            this.filtros.push(new Row(item.id, item.nombre));
                            unicos.push(item.categoria, item.id, item.nombre);
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: No te carga el componente o no te carga los datos del componente?

Comment: No me carga los datos del componente

Answer (score 0):

Para no tener este tipo de problemas, ya que lo que puede estar pasando es que no se ejecute el onInit, es mejor trabajar de forma reactiva.

Sería conveniente suscribirse al observable desde el html con el pipe async.

Y en el componente, el codigo quedaría más o menos así:

```
let elementosFiltrados = this.servService.getFiltar(this.url).pipe(
map(
//filtro los elementos y los devuelvo.
)
);
```

y en el HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elementosFiltrados | async">...
```

Comment: estuve revisando y el onInit si se ejecuta, tengo un console log que imprime los datos del get cada que se ejecuta y como tal si me lo imprime, lo único es que la petición get ya no se ejecuta cuando le doy en regresar ya me imprime el mensaje sin el resultado del get